# Web API v2 SelfHost middleware security AuthenticateCoreAsync does not prevent access

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api2, owin, middleware, self-hosting

I was following the instructions on http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/11/client-certificate-authentication-middleware-for-katana/ but also followed Diminic's Pluralishight video on Web API security as I was trying to apply a client certificate authentication on my self hosted Web API v2 project.
I call the service from Advanced REST Client Chrome extension app, meaning it does not contain a client certificate in the request, and I see that cert == null but after that I still get a valid response from the server. 
Is there something missing from this tutorial code?

```
public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions
{
    public X509CertificateValidator Validator { get; set; }
    public bool CreateExtendedClaimSet { get; set; }

    public ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions() : base(“X.509″)
    {
        Validator = X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrust;
        CreateExtendedClaimSet = false;
    }
}

public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationHandler : 
      AuthenticationHandler<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        var cert = Context.Get<X509Certificate2>(“ssl.ClientCertificate”);

        if (cert == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        try
        {
            Options.Validator.Validate(cert);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        var claims = GetClaimsFromCertificate(
          cert, cert.Issuer, Options.CreateExtendedClaimSet);

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaims(claims);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
          identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(ticket);
    }
}


public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationMiddleware : 
      AuthenticationMiddleware<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public ClientCertificateAuthenticationMiddleware(
      OwinMiddleware next, 
      ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions options)
        : base(next, options)
    { }

    protected override    AuthenticationHandler<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new ClientCertificateAuthenticationHandler();
    }
}


app.UseClientCertificateAuthentication();
app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you decorate your ApiController with the `Authorize` attribute?

```
[Authorize]
public class MyWebApiController : ApiController
{
}
```

Otherwise, the status code of your request will be 200 and not 401 even if the username/password do not match.